# How can I set Intellij to copy resource directories and not just the directory content?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'd like to set a folder in my Intellij project as a test resource folder and have the Intellij IDE copy the whole folder to my output directory and keep the top level folder in place.

For example, here's a basic project structure:

```
src/
 - stack/
  - overflow/
   - question/
    - SomeClass.java
tst/
 - stack/
  - overflow/
   - question/
    - SomeClassTest.java
files/
 - testfile.txt
 - testdoc.doc
 - testpdf.pdf
test-configuration/
 - default.properties
 - test-configuration.xml
```

Should compile and create an output directory like:

```
out/
 - stack/
  - overflow/
   - question/
    - SomeClass.class
 - test-configuration/
  - default.properties
  - test-configuration.xml
 - files/
  - testfile.txt
  - testdoc.doc
  - testpdf.pdf
```

The problem is, just marking the **test-configuration** or **files** directories as *Test Resources Root* (or *Resources Root*) folders, always produces the following output directory structure:

```
out/
 - stack/
  - overflow/
   - question/
    - SomeClass.class
 - default.properties
 - test-configuration.xml
 - testfile.txt
 - testdoc.doc
 - testpdf.pdf
```

Intellij seems to only copy the contents of the resource folders and not the whole directory. Is there a way to set Intellij to copy the root directory to maintain the directory structure in the output?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why? This looks like a XY problem to me. What is it that requires you to have empty directories in the classpath, since you won't be able to load anything out of them anyway?

Comment: @fge, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not trying to have empty directories, I'm trying to have resource directories added with all of the contents, but including the root directory so that I can run JUnit tests in Intellij that require Spring configurations to be loaded from *.xml files.

Comment: OK, I see; well, the quick solution (and best imho) would just be to create a directory in which you would put both test-configuration/ and files/, and use that as a test resources directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such way. A resource **root** is just that: a directory the contents of which is copied to the **root** of the output directory. If you need to have additional structure, you need to create a "resources" directory, mark it as a resource root, and move your "test-configuration" and "files" directories into it.